# Go to anchor point in Dreamweaver server behavior

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

I´m using a **Dreamweaver server behavior** to create an insert into a MySQL database with PHP. In the pop-up menu to configure the insert, I have the option to go to a specific page after that.

I need to:

1) Go to a specific anchor point in some page, and

2) Show a message after the insert.

The problem is that I write **page.php#anchor** in the goto field, and it doesn´t work, because the result outputs **page.php#anchor?**, with a final interrogation mark. The original Dreamweaver code for this is:

```
  $insertGoTo = "page.php#anchor";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
```

So, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the anchor at the end instead of the beginning

```
$insertGoTo = "page.php";
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
  $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}
$insertGoTo .= "#anchor";
```

Or if you know you won't have a query string to pass along, delete all that logic for keeping it.

```
$insertGoTo = "page.php#anchor";
```

Comment: It really works! Thanks Dan. That's the problem when we use Dreamweaver and not our own code instead. I need to do my 'homework'.